# bottone1 cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

Like before, I'm doing some tutorials, but I think the one that I rewrote I made some mistakes in the rewriting of the code. In this part of the guide I should add two buttons. I have done all the steps but:

> bottone1 cannot be resolved or is not a field
>   
> bottone2 cannot be resolved or is not a field

Here is the code:

```
package marco.prova;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;

public class Main extends Activity {
    private TextView textView1;
    private Button bottone1;
    private Button bottone2;
    /** Called when the activity is first created.*/
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.testo1);
      textView1.setText("Testo modificato tramite codice 1");
      bottone1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bottone1);
      bottone2 = (Button) findViewByid(R.id.bottone2);
      bottone1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick (View view) {
          textView1.setText("E' stato premuto il bottone 1");
        }
      });
      bottone2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick (View view) {
          textView1.setText("E' stato premuto il bottone 1");
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

Hoping for some help. Thank you.

here the layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"> >

    <TextView
        android:text="Testo di default TextView1"
        android:id="@+id/testo1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </TextView>

    <Button
        android:text="Bottone1"
        android:id="@+id/bottone1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </Button>   

    <Button
        android:text="Bottone2"
        android:id="@+id/bottone2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </Button>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It's probably not defined in your layout. Can we see the XML of your layout? If it is defined there, try cleaning the project.

Answer (score 1):

**`Project -> Clean`** is the solution when you get such kind of errors.

Clean your project and build it again.

Or if it still doesn't work, delete the generated R.java and build the project again to create the generated code from scratch.

Also, `setContentView(R.layout.<filename>);` as the name of your XML file is `<filename>.xml` in which the buttons are defined.

Comment: anyone have some other suggestion ?

Comment: @MarcoLivio : What is the name of your XML file ? If it is `layout.xml`, you should be using `setContentView(R.layout.layout);`.

Comment: the name of my xml file is activity_main.xml

Comment: Oh, forgive me and cleaning still does not help it ? :(